# What does the "name" parameter mean in the syscall_32.tbl linux file?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I am adding some custom system calls to linux Fedora and I am currently trying to update "syscall_32.tbl". The only hiccup is that I am not too sure what the `name` field for the call table means.

Is this something we just make up? As in a name that we decide to call this particular system call?

For example the structure of the table is:

```
<number> <abi> <name> <entry point> <compat entry point>
```

For the `<name>` section is this a parameter that we decide on and just enter there? Or is it something more specific like the filename that the system call is located in?

Comment: When I tried a couple years ago syscalls were impossible to extend without kernel recompiltaion. Are you writing a module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a system call table in the kernel, listing all the system calls and their implementing functions. The user-land requests a system call by specifying the index number of the syscall. Therefore this index number must match between kernel compilations and user-land code compilations. Since this list is an error-prone thing to maintain, the system call table that you have found was introduced, and code is generated from it automatically. That table correlates the system calls: their index number, the name to be used in the user-land, and the kernel function name implementing the system call. From this table, the `Makefile` generates the header files.

There is a header file `syscalls_xx.h`, it defines the table within the kernel (it lists all the kernel functions implementing the syscalls by their index).

There is another header file `unistd_xx.h`, it provides `#define`'s for the user-land, listing the syscall index numbers by name. The *name* field you are asking will get into this list, by which the user-land can refer to this system call: `__NR_<xxx>`. This header file is copied and used in user-space code so that the syscall index numbers can be referenced by name (see the glibc sources, how these are used).

syscall_32.tbl:

```
350     i386    finit_module            sys_finit_module
```

unistd_32.h:

```
#define __NR_finit_module 350
```

syscalls_32.h:

```
__SYSCALL_I386(350, sys_finit_module, sys_finit_module)
```

Comment: Ok so the names are essentially the user-land function names that map to the system calls. So I could write a c file and use *name*(*needed arguments*) where name is a particular syscall name instead of the entry point name... correct?

Comment: No, you dont' have to. Those names are the strings used in the #define labels. You can name your user-space function whatever you like - inside that function you'll use the #define label from that header file, and nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you also can use the complete list of system calls with their relative system call number in strace source code. e.g for i386 system here is the link:

[syscallent.h (i386) in strace sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/strace/code/ci/master/tree/linux/i386/syscallent.h)