# Parameters of files syscall_32.tbl, syscall_64.tbl in build linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls, kernel-module

I'm praticing to build a new linux kernel on virtual machine. I have some question about 2 files `syscall_32.tbl` and `syscall_64.tbl` in step import parameters of a module in them.

I'm know that file `syscall_32.tbl` have 5 parameters `[number] [abi] [name], [entry point], [compat entry point]`, and file `syscall_64.tbl` have 4 without `[compat entry point]`.

I have some questions that I can't find answer for them.

1. `[number]`: what is range value of this column. I find out that the numbers are union and increasing sequence. If now I import new with large number (such as 10^6), is it OK?
2. `[abi]`: I know that in file `syscall_64.tbl`, the value of column maybe `common`, `64`, `x32`. What is meaning of each value? Why is different between them? And why machine 64-bit have value `x32` in this column?
3. `[name]`: I know that `[entry point]` and `[compat entry point]` is used for function to run the syscall. And when user call system call, we don't need call the `name`, we only use the `[number]` and kernel space use `[entry point]` to run. What is a reason for this column (`[name]`)?

Thanks for your view and answer. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For different binaries to interact, they need to agree on a set of interfaces, e.g. the size of types and layout (padding) of `struct`s. On amd64, GNU/Linux supports three ABIs natively:

- [i386](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/abi386-4.pdf): For compatibility with x86 32-bit binaries. System calls are defined in [syscall_32.tbl](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.14/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl)
- [x86_64](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf): Native 64-bit binaries. System calls are defined [syscall_64.tbl](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.14/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl) with abi=64
- [x32](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnx4MzJhYml8Z3g6MzVkYzQwOWIwOGU4YzViYw): ILP32 (32-bit `int`, `long` and pointers), but with amd64 goodies: e.g. registers are 64-bit and there is more of them than in i386. System calls are defined [syscall_64.tbl](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.14/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl) with abi=x32

A binary's ABI is configured at compilation time (`-m32`, `-m64` and `-mx32` respectively for GCC), but the kernel runs in long mode in all three cases and [sometimes conversions are necessary](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/process/adding-syscalls.html#compatibility-system-calls-x86) to account for ABI differences.

Regarding your questions:

1. `[number]`: Size depends on the system call convention. e.g. with `int 80h`, the system call number is passed through the 32-bit wide eax.
2. `[abi]`: "common" system calls can be used for both amd64 ABIs, but some, like those with pointers to `struct`s, need special handling to account for ABI differences.
3. `[name]`: Linux provides headers with system call number definitions, e.g.
   `#define __NR_exit 1`. The macro name is generated from the `[name]` column. See [this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648470/what-does-the-name-parameter-mean-in-the-syscall-32-tbl-linux-file).